# overriding helm values selenium-grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, kubernetes-helm

i'm using below helm command to install selenium grid but its not effecting on max concurrenct sessions

```
helm install selenium-grid  --set hub.extraJavaOptions=-Dwebdriver.server.session.timeout=180   --set chromeNode.extraJavaOptions=-Dwebdriver.chrome.maxSessions=2  --set firefoxNode.extraJavaOptions=-Dwebdriver.gecko.max-sessions=2   --set global.maxConcurrency=2   --set chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables[0].name=SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS   --set chromeNode.extraEnvironmentVariables[0].value=true  docker-selenium/selenium-grid
```